# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

Como posso resolver o problema de "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"? Não consigo encontrar onde estaria o erro.

Segue abaixo as declarações.

```
typedef struct{
  int dia,mes,ano;
}data;

typedef struct {
  char matricula[10];
  data _matricula;
  data _conclusao;
  char curso[25];
  char universidade[50];

}universitario;

typedef struct {
  data _deposito;
  float renda;  
}poupanca;

typedef struct {

  float salario;
  char orgao_trabalha[50];
  char cargo[12];
  data _contratacao;
}salario;


typedef struct{ 

}corrente;

typedef struct {

  char nome [25];
  char sobrenome[25];
  char endereco[50];
  char email[25];
  char telefone[12];
  char CPF[12];
  int ID; 
  union conta_tipo{
    universitario u;    
    poupanca p;
    salario s;
    corrente c;
  };
}cadastro;


struct cadastro c1;
```

---

```
void preencher_cadastro (struct cadastro *p,int tipo_conta){

  printf ("Insira o nome do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
  setbuf (stdin,NULL);
  fgets (p->nome,25,stdin);[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
  printf("Insira o sobrenome do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
  setbuf (stdin,NULL);
  fgets (p->sobrenome,25,stdin);
  setbuf (stdin,NULL);
```

Segundo a IDE, o erro esta em todos os fgets.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma alma desce do purgatório para o inferno quando alguém usa o Dev-C++...

Answer (score 2):

Ao usar o tipo, está usando "struct cadastro", quando deveria usar apenas "cadastro", já que o tipo cadastro já está devidamente definido como struct.

Se a struct estivesse definida desta forma:

`struct cadastro { ... membros ... }`

Aí seria necessário usar 'struct cadastro' a cada uso da estrutura. Mas a forma com typedef é muito mais usual porque evita ter de repetir a palavra-chave.

Em C++ creio que a regra é um pouco diferente: declarar 'struct cadastro' tem o mesmo efeito prático que usar typedef, e basta usar o nome do tipo (sem struct) no código.